# Can't Install 'baseballr' Package

Tags: r, devtools

I'm using the following code to install the `baseballr` package from GitHub:

```
require(devtools)
install_github("BillPetti/baseballr")
require(baseballr)
```

However, I keep getting the following error when running `require(baseballr)`:

```
Loading required package: baseballr
Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘baseballr’
```

Also, when I run `install_github("BillPetti/baseballr")`, I get the following error:

```
package ‘glue’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Error: (converted from warning) cannot remove prior installation of package ‘glue’
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) :
  skipping pax global extended headers
2: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) :
  skipping pax global extended headers
```

`devtools` is properly installed but I'm just not sure why `baseballr` won't properly install. The documentation for the package can be found [here](http://billpetti.github.io/baseballr/about/).

Comment: Do you get any output when you run `install_github("BillPetti/baseballr")`? The error message you show is just from the `require()`, right?

Comment: When i run `install_github("BillPetti/baseballr"` I am told that there are packages that have more recent versions available. Then I enter `1` to update all packages and I get the following error: `package ‘glue’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Error: (converted from warning) cannot remove prior installation of package ‘glue’
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) :
  skipping pax global extended headers
2: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) :
  skipping pax global extended headers` I modified my question to show this.

Comment: What version of R are you using? If it can't remove a previous version, you probably already have something loaded in your workspace. Try restarting R and then running the `install_github` command. Also, try not installing the more recent versions of packages unless they are required.

Comment: I am using version 3.5.2

Comment: it's not an ideal solution but you should be able to avoid upgrading `glue` by adding `upgrade = "ask"`